# Final class and Final method - Mocking with Mockito 2

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4

Is the feature provided by Mockito 2 to mock final methods and final classes using org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker(mock-maker-inline) generally available(released) or still in the incubation phase. I am using mockito-core-2.23.4 artifact in my application. Need suggestions in mocking the final classes and methods. Is it advisable to use this approach or look for alternate options?

Answer (score 4):

As of Mockito 2.x, Mockito now supports mocking of final classes and methods.

Example:

Say we have a `MyList` class shown below as the collaborator in test cases.

We’ll add a new `finalMethod` to this class:

```
public class MyList extends AbstractList {
    final public int finalMethod() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And we'll also extend it with a final subclass:

```
public final class FinalList extends MyList {     
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Before Mockito can be used for mocking final classes and methods, it needs to be configured.

We need to add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:

> mock-maker-inline

Mockito checks the extensions directory for configuration files when it is loaded. This file enables the mocking of final methods and classes.

**Mock a Final Method:**

Once Mockito is properly configured, a final method can be mocked like any other:

```
@Test
public void whenMockFinalMethodMockWorks() {

    MyList myList = new MyList();

    MyList mock = mock(MyList.class);
    when(mock.finalMethod()).thenReturn(1);

    assertNotEquals(mock.finalMethod(), myList.finalMethod());
}
```

By creating a concrete instance and a mock instance of MyList, we can compare the values returned by both versions of `finalMethod()` and verify that the mock is called.

**Mock a Final Class:**

Mocking a final class is just as easy as mocking any other class:

```
@Test
public void whenMockFinalClassMockWorks() {

    FinalList finalList = new FinalList();

    FinalList mock = mock(FinalList.class);
    when(mock.size()).thenReturn(2);

    assertNotEquals(mock.size(), finalList.size());
}
```

Similar to the test above, we create a concrete instance and a mock instance of our final class, mock a method and verify that the mocked instance behaves differently.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final

Comment: Hey Mebin! Thanks for your response! Even I went through the same tutorial earlier and I am clear from an implementation standpoint. My question was more from an usability of the feature whether it is released or still in the incubation phase? As per this https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods, it is still in the incubation phase. Nowhere in the documentation I came across about its release status. I was debating whether to use this before its release.